# How to show tooltip on image hover in Amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts4

I'm using Amcharts version 4 to plot Line charts. I've a huge data points of almost 30 years of daily data . some points have description for example the data set look like this .

```
[
  {value:9,date:2020-09-09},
  {value:100,date:2020-09-10 , value_Note:"company gains lots of profit" , value_Image : "https://flagicons.lipis.dev/flags/4x3/bb.svg"} ....  
]
```

As the data suggests I have to shown flag image on date `2020-09-10` and on hover to the flag I have to show the description `"company gains lots of profit"`

The only problem is that on line series I am showing tooltip by

```
lineSeries.tooltipHTML = `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('dd MMM, yyyy')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
```

and for Image related things I have done this.

```
 var bullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
        bullet.adapter.add("rotation", function (rotation, target) {
            if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.valueY < 0) {
                return 180;
            }
            return rotation;
        });
        bullet.disabled = true;
        bullet.propertyFields.disabled = EnableBullet;
        var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
        image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
        image.width = 30;
        image.height = 30;
        image.dy = 1;
        image.dx = 1;
        image.cloneTooltip =
        image.tooltipHTML = `<div class="ChartToolTip">${tooltipdata}</div>`;
        image.showTooltipOn = "hover";
        image.propertyFields.href = "" + BulletField + "";;
        image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

Now on hovering the image it is showing the tooltip of the line itself , when i remove the below line

```
lineSeries.tooltipHTML = `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('dd MMM, yyyy')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
```

Than it shows me the tooltip of image on hover , is it possible to show the tooltip of image itself on hovering image instead of line tooltip.

I have found a solution

```
lineSeries.adapter.add("tooltipHTML", function (text, target) {
            if (target._tooltipDataItem && target._tooltipDataItem._dataContext[NoteKey] != undefined) {
                return `<div class="ChartToolTip">${target._tooltipDataItem._dataContext[NoteKey]}</div>`;
            }
            if (FiscalPeriodValue == "IntraDay") {
                return `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
            } else {
                return `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('dd MMM, yyyy')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
            }
        });
```

but the problem is that i have 50000000 points so the points are close it is not showing tooltip of notes on hovering image , unless i zoom the chart , is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

Found a clue which works fine

```
 image.events.on("over", function(event) {
     lineSeries.tooltipHTML = `<div class="ChartToolTip">${event.target.dataItem._dataContext.value_Note}</div>`;
     });
     image.events.on("out", function(event) {
     if (FiscalPeriodValue == "IntraDay") {
         lineSeries.tooltipHTML = `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
     } else {
         lineSeries.tooltipHTML = `<div style="">{dateX.formatDate('dd MMM, yyyy')}: {valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}</div>`;
     }
     });
```